# Models passed to `fit` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, compilation, transformer-model

I am trying to follow this code but on another data set:https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#encoder_layer
I needed to compile and fit the model. however, I get this error while running; I don't know what it means:

```
 Models passed to `fit` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, found: ['tar', 'enc_padding_mask', 'look_ahead_mask', 'dec_padding_mask'].
```

Here it is the model:

```
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size, 
               target_vocab_size, pe_input, pe_target, rate=0.1,**kwargs,):
    super(Transformer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, 
                           input_vocab_size, pe_input, rate)

    self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, 
                           target_vocab_size, pe_target, rate)

    self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)
  def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'dff':self.dff,
            'input_vocab_size':self.input_vocab_size,
            'target_vocab_size':self.target_vocab_size,
            'pe_input':self.pe_input,
            'pe_target':self.pe_target,
            #'vocab_size': self.vocab_size,
            'num_layers': self.num_layers,
            #'units': self.units,
            'd_model': self.d_model,
            'num_heads': self.num_heads,
            'rate': self.rate,
        })
        return config

  def call(self, inp, tar, training, enc_padding_mask, 
           look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask):

    enc_output = self.encoder(inp, training, enc_padding_mask)  # (batch_size, inp_seq_len, d_model)

    # dec_output.shape == (batch_size, tar_seq_len, d_model)
    dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
        tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)

    final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)  # (batch_size, tar_seq_len, target_vocab_size)
    #    return final_output, attention_weights


    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, dec_inputs], outputs=outputs, name=name)
```

and creating the model, compiling it, and fitting it as follows:

```
transformer = Transformer(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
                          input_vocab_size, target_vocab_size, 
                          pe_input=input_vocab_size, 
                          pe_target=target_vocab_size,
                          rate=dropout_rate)

transformer.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=[accuracy])

transformer.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

EDIT: Bases on @Geeocode updated the def function in transformer class to be:

```
def call(self, inp, tar, enc_padding_mask,look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask, training=False,):

    enc_output = self.encoder(inp, training, enc_padding_mask)  # (batch_size, inp_seq_len, d_model)

    # dec_output.shape == (batch_size, tar_seq_len, d_model)
    dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
        tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)

    final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)  # (batch_size, tar_seq_len, target_vocab_size)
    return final_output, attention_weights
```

However, I still get the same error

Answer (score 10):

The reason why you got the error is because `self.call` only takes two variables an `input` and a `training` flag. If you have multiple input variables, they are passed as a tuple. Therefore, you can have a function definition similar to the following:

```py
def call(self, input, training):
  inp, tar, enc_padding_mask,look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask = input
  ...
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: It is not a good idea to name a variable as a Pythonic keyword, such as `input`. I would implore you to follow PEP-8 best practices.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in the documentation, as we can see on github, that if we want to inherit `tf.keras.Model`, then we only can have one `training` parameter beside of the `inputs` at the definition of the `call()` method and that is the error message complains about:

> If you subclass `Model`, you can optionally have a `training` argument
>   (boolean) in `call`, which you can use to specify a different behavior
>   in training and inference

````
  """
  If you subclass `Model`, you can optionally have
  a `training` argument (boolean) in `call`, which you can use to specify
  a different behavior in training and inference:
  ```python
  import tensorflow as tf
  class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
      super(MyModel, self).__init__()
      self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
      self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
      x = self.dense1(inputs)
      if training:
        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
      return self.dense2(x)
  model = MyModel()
  ```
  """
````

I suggest you to create an issue on github refering it.

Comment: I did so but I had this error: AttributeError: 'Transformer' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did check your update and I added training=false in the def call however, I have the same issue of Models passed to `fit` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments

Comment: @Mee You can not pass only one optional parameter as the `call()` method's parameter. I think, that the documentation is buggy, so simply it doesn't work so, what they wrote in it. The error message says that your `call()` method can not have more parameter, then `training` parameter, yo you can not define your `call()` methode as `def call(self, inp, tar, training, enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask):` you can only have `def call(self, inp, training):`, where the `training` parameter is optional.

Comment: @kevinsu my last opinion is still the same

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out you can only have two positional arguments for the `call` method of your model: the input data and a boolean flag for training. However, as the error message hints at, you can have keyword arguments. So a method like this should work:

```
def call(self, inp: tf.Tensor, training: bool, **kwargs):
    tar = kwargs['tar']  # Note will raise an exception if the argument is missing
    enc_padding_mask = kwargs['enc_padding_mask']
    look_ahead_mask = kwargs['look_ahead_mask']
    dec_padding_mask = kwargs['dec_padding_mask']

    ...

# Then later you use it like:
transformer = # Construct your Transformer model
result = transformer(
    inp, 
    training, 
    tar=tar, 
    enc_padding_mask=enc_padding_mask, 
    look_ahead_mask=look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask=dec_padding_mask
)
```